# Node Express + Sequelize findAll return SequelizeDatabaseError on empty database

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, sequelize.js

I'am trying to retrive a simple list (no where clause for now) of Orders (SQLite).
I correctly config Node Express Server,router and models. My collection is still empty.
When I try the route

```
router.get('/orders', (req, res) => {
Order.findAll({order: [['updateAt', 'DESC']]})
 .then(orders => {
  res.send(orders);
 })
 .catch(error => {
  res.send({error: error});
 });
});
```

The response is

```
{
"error": {
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
        "errno": 1,
        "code": "SQLITE_ERROR",
        "sql": "SELECT `id`, `order_num`, `order_date`, `status`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Orders` AS `Order` ORDER BY `Order`.`updateAt` DESC;"
    },
    "original": {
        "errno": 1,
        "code": "SQLITE_ERROR",
        "sql": "SELECT `id`, `order_num`, `order_date`, `status`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Orders` AS `Order` ORDER BY `Order`.`updateAt` DESC;"
    },
    "sql": "SELECT `id`, `order_num`, `order_date`, `status`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Orders` AS `Order` ORDER BY `Order`.`updateAt` DESC;"
}
```

I do not find the correct way to intercept the case of *O(zero) Order found* or *no data found* without generating an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your column names.  This code `Order.findAll({order: [['updateAt', 'DESC']]})` may be wrong, as the query in the error messages suggests the column is actually update**d**At